# Get custom field outside the loop array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to the $appLink variable with a custom field value outside of the loop. I'm using Wurfl to detect the users device,  I'd like to echo the custom field value for the URL. This is what I have but I can't get it to work. Can anyone help please?

```
 else if ($os == 'iOS') 
  {  
  global $wp_query;
  $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
  $appLink = echo get_post_meta($postid, 'ios_app_link_sb', true);
  wp_reset_query();
  }
```

Comment: `$appLink = echo get_post_meta($postid, 'ios_app_link_sb', true);` are you sure about that line ????

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 1):

It should be either

```
 echo get_post_meta($postid, 'ios_app_link_sb', true);
```

or

```
 $appLink = get_post_meta($postid, 'ios_app_link_sb', true);
 echo $appLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this debug $postid.

```
Print_r($id)
```

if $postid is true, you check name key meta 'ios_app_link_sb' is exist value?